# Overriding web.xml filter configuration

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, cors, web.xml

Is there any elegant way to override web.xml configuration and add something to cors.allowOrigin from a java class. My allowOrigin needs to be generated by code not hard coded.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
      <param-value>ORIGINS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</filter>
```

Of course I can override CORSFilter but there I have

```
@Override
public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig)
    throws ServletException {}
```

where FilterConfig is a read only interface operates on Enumerations which are read only as well... generally solving the problem this way force me to write a lot of additional strange code. Is there any shortest solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is part of the container and read only by design. To over wide you need to make your shadow copy and refer to the read only for defaults/ things you need to change.

For another project we needed to add params in a servlet so we did this

```
package com.sel2in.req
```

import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public class WrapedRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private Map<String, String> myP = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private HttpServletRequest req;

    public WrapedRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        req = request;
    }

    public void setParameter(String s, String v) {
        myP.put(s, v);
    }

    public java.lang.String getParameter(java.lang.String name) {
        String s = myP.get(name);
        if (s != null)
            return s;
        return req.getParameter(name);
    }
           //over ride more if needed

}
```

And to use it

```
wrpReq = new WrapedRequest(req);
wrpReq.setParameter("userid", username);
```

Similarly you will need to do this with the FilterConfig

Comment: hehe this is what I called "additional strange code" in my description :) Of course you are correct this will work. The same wrapping technique I have to use to modify Enumeration containing parameter names because it is similar read only interface. I am just trying to avoid this.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem this way. In the end it was not that bad.